# How to include a dependency in an Android gradle file based on flavorDimension?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have an Android project with 5 flavors and 2 flavorDimensions.

See Below:

```js
flavorDimensions "env", "device"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            dimension "env"
        }
        staging {
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
            dimension "env"
        }
        prod {
            applicationIdSuffix ""
            dimension "env"
        }
        amazon {
            dimension "device"
        }
        google {
            dimension "device"
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to only include a dependency to one flavorDimension instead of just one flavor? Basically I have a dependency I only want included in googleDev, googleStaging, and googleProd (but not the amazon dimension)

Is there an easy way to do this without repeating each dependency 3 times?

Comment: AFAIK, you should be able to use `googleImplementation` instead of `implementation` in your module's `build.gradle` for those dependencies.

Comment: @CommonsWare you're right. I didn't know googleImplementation would cover the dev, staging, and prod flavors. Thank you!!